# Error rolling multiple (ex.100) dice in my python code. **Example included**

Tags: python

My problem is that when I try to roll a large number (ex. 100d2, 200d2) dice at once it fails.

**Here is the code with an example.**

```
import random

def get_damage(attack, defense):
 if attack > defense:        # Should the get_roll be used here?
   return attack - defense
 else:
   return 0

def get_roll(rollstring):
   repeat = int(rollstring.split('d')[0])
   torandom = int(rollstring.split('d')[1])
   for i in range(repeat):
       result = random.randint(repeat, torandom)
   return result

def main_menu():
 x = int(input("How many rolls do you want to take?"))
 z = 0
 list = []
 for roll in range(0,x):
   print("Input attack and defense roll", roll + 1, ":", end="")
   y = input()
   list = list + y.split(",")
 for element in range(0,x):
   attack = list[z]
   defense = list[z+1]
   attack = get_roll(attack)
   defense = get_roll(defense)
   print ("Attack:", attack, "Defense:", defense, "Damage:", get_damage(attack, defense))
   z = z + 2

main_menu()
```

I was told to use the **get_roll()** where I indicated it in the code above.

I think this will solve the problem of not allowing more than a small number of dice to roll.

**Below is the output for a successful and unsuccessful run:**

**Success:**

```
How many rolls do you want to take?2
Input attack and defense roll 1 :2d4903,1d3903
Input attack and defense roll 2 :1d939,1d4583
Attack: 4570 Defense: 3202 Damage: 1368
Attack: 258 Defense: 985 Damage: 0
```

**Fail:**

````
Input attack and defense roll 1 :400d7,800d5
Input attack and defense roll 2 :9823d293,85392d8302
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 41, in <module>
    main_menu()
  File "main.py", line 33, in main_menu
    attack = get_roll(attack)
  File "main.py", line 17, in get_roll
    result = random.randint(repeat, torandom)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 248, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 226, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d, %d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (400, 8, -392) ```
````

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.  Don't expect us to enter your test data, especially for an undocumented interface.

Comment: randint takes a min and max value, not a repeat value.

Comment: Next problem: I think if you roll 2 D6 you want the sum of both rolls back. At the moment you only return the result of the last roll and that doesn't really make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little basic debugging shows the problem: with repeat=400 and torandom=7, you called

```
   result = random.randint(repeat, torandom)
```

The range (400, 7) is empty.  You need

```
   result = random.randint(1, torandom+1)
```